# Does somebody here used NotifyMe library in Android?

Tags: java, android

Does anyone has used the [NotifyMe][1] Android library? I've tried everything but it doesn't seem to work. Anyone who tried this and worked Please help me. It doesn't notify.

```
event.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
 Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
NotifyMe notifyMe = new NotifyMe.Builder(getApplicationContext())
.title("Testing")
 .content("This is a sample event notification.")
.color(255,0,0,255)
.led_color(255,255,255,255)
.time(now)
.addAction(intent,"Snooze",false)
.key("test")
.addAction(new Intent(),"Dismiss",true,false)
.addAction(intent,"Done")
.large_icon(R.drawable.ic_event)
.build();

  [1]: https://github.com/jakebonk/NotifyMe
```

Comment: The information provided here is not sufficient to understand your problem. The same sample code is available in [NotifiyMe](https://github.com/jakebonk/NotifyMe) library's README file. You need to [edit] the question and add some [mcve] which shows how did you try that library? Version of Android OS you're testing on? Is there any error (log) while setting notification? etc.

Comment: Sorry about my question. what I mean is, I've tried what is on the README instructions but it simply didn't work. and it does not have any error log. my current version of android is Marshmallow.

Comment: _"I've tried what is on the README instructions but it simply didn't work."_ Yeah that's what I'm asking here. We need to look into your code. We need to check what's going on in your code. :)

Comment: Here is the code sir

Comment: Any log or error exists? If you have logs, please post them too.

Answer (score 2):

I know its too late to answer. But I'm answering it so that it can be helpful to someone.

The problem is not with the library, but you are using AndroidX which is the problem for why the library is not working for your project.

The simple solution is:

1. Load library as a module
2. Open NotificationPublisher.java in the library/NofityMe package. You will now see errors for NotificationCompat.Builder
3. Change the import from

   ```
   import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
   ```

   to

   ```
   import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
   ```